# Any built-in do the job `range(len(lst))`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I find myself often use something like

```
for i in range(len(lst1)): lst1[i] += lst2[i]
```

Is there a built-in equivalent to `range(len(.))`?

(BTW, I use Python3.)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `range(len(...))` is hardly if ever useful in python. If you use it often, it's time to reconsider your practices. In your example, the pythonic way is `new_list = [a + b for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2)]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

better use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
 for index,x in enumerate(lst1):
      lst1[index] += lst2[index]
```

`enumerate()` returns an `enumerate` object, which contains `tuples`, where first item of a tuple is index and second is the element. (by default the index starts from 0, you can change that by passing an optional argument to `enumerate()`)

**example:**

```
In [50]: lst1=['a','b','c','s']

In [51]: list(enumerate(lst1))         #default index values, i.e 0
Out[51]: [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 's')]

In [53]: list(enumerate(lst1,1))       #index started at 1 
Out[53]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 's')]
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `enumerate` before. It is what I need. Thx!

Answer (score 11):

```
for i, e in enumerate(lst2):
    lst1[i] += e
```

or

```
lst1 = [e1 + e2 for e1, e2 in zip(lst1, lst2)]
```

Comment: @updogliu: unless you have numbers to back up your statement, you might as well delete it. It clearly more efficient than anything posted elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the latter is faster, I just tried. I didn't note that Python's `+=` does NOT increase an integer like that in C, it create a new integer.